# sql join Many-To-Many - 3 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, many-to-many

I have 3 tables in sqlserver :

```
tbl_Users            -  User_ID, User_Name  
tbl_Roles            -  Role_ID, Role_Name  
tbl_Users_Roles_MTM  -  User_ID, Role_ID
```

A user can have multiple roles assigned to him, and that will show in the Many-To-Many table.

In my stored-procedure I need `Role_Name` which are **NOT** assigned to a specific `User_ID` (which is given as a parameter).
I guess I should use an INNER JOIN (or a LEFT one...).

There are numerous entries in SO and other forums with questions nearly similar to this but not quite. I experimented a lot but by now I completely lost my hands and feet!

Thank you all.

**EDIT :**
With the help of the good people of SO, I got it to work :

```
SELECT r.Role_Name
       FROM tbl_Roles r
       WHERE NOT EXISTS(
             SELECT 1 
             FROM tbl_Users_Roles_MTM ur
             WHERE ur.User_ID = @User_ID
             AND   ur.Role_ID = r.Role_ID);
```

SO people are awesome!!!!!

Comment: If you add some sample table data and expected result it would be easier to understand your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT r.Role_Name
FROM tbl_Roles r
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM tbl_Users_Roles_MTM ur
    WHERE ur.User_ID = @User_ID
    AND ur.Role_ID = r.Role_ID);
```

Comment: The last line should be : `AND ur.Role_ID = r.Role_ID)` and it works beautifully.  Please edit your answer and I'll mark it it as "answer".  Now I'll check out the other suggestions brought up here. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Oops, my bad, what a terrible typo! :(

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Roles
WHERE Role_Name = @rolename
  AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 
                 FROM tbl_Roles AS r
                 INNER JOIN tbl_Users_Roles_MTM AS ur ON ur.Role_ID = r.Role_ID
                 WHERE r.role_Name = @rolename
                   AND ur.User_ID = @User_ID);
```

The `NOT EXISTS` predicate will ensure that the role is not assigned to any user.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT r.*
FROM tbl_Roles r
LEFT JOIN tbl_Users_Roles_MTM ur
  ON r.Role_ID = ur.Role_ID
  AND ur.User_ID = @User_ID
WHERE ur.User_ID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this

```
select roles.Role_Name 
from tbl_Roles as roles
    left join tbl_Users_Roles_MTM as userRoles
       on userRoles.Role_ID = roles.Role_ID
       and userRoles.[User_ID] = @User_ID
where userRoles.Role_ID is null
```

Basically left join and then select only those rows, where it has not been joined